# Spring Data: return null in update will rollback transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

In my code, the update method probably will return null, and it will affect the transaction where invoke this method.

As I know only throw runtime exception or user specify the checked exception will trigger the rollback action, so does return null will trigger it too?

Service1

```
public class Service1 {

    @Autowired
    private Service2 service2;

    @Autowried
    private Service1Repository service1Repository;

    @Transactional
    public Entity1 update(Entity1 entity) {
        service1Repository.update(entity);

        // if this method return null, above update will rollback. Otherwise, it will be executed success.
        service2.update(entity.getId());

        return entity;
    }
}
```

Service2:

```
public class Service2 {
    @Autowired
    private Service2Repository service2Repository;

    @Transactional
    public Entity2 update(Integer id) {
        Entity2 entity = service2Repository.findOne(id);

        // No need to update HIDDEN status entity
        if (Status.HIDDEN.equals(entity.getStatus())) {
            return null;
        }

        entity.setOtherAttribute("xyz");
        service2Repository.update(entity);

        return entity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return `null` from `Service2.update()` method will not rollback database transaction, as it is normal code execution.

Also, as stated in Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-txadvice-settings):

> Any RuntimeException triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does not.

Comment: yes, I also think so, but this actually happened in my code, so I just want to double confirm this situation is not the case.

Comment: I mean if my Service2.update() gets executed, and if it returns null, Service1.update() won't update any data. It looks like service1Repository.update() will rollback data.

Comment: I don't think that should be the case. Something else must be happening. You can verify that `service1Repository.update(entity)` is executing successfully and that main update method successfully returns.